# Error de INSERT INTO codigo php

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, mysqli

Estoy creando un sistema de motor de búsqueda tipo `Google`, entre otros. el problema es cuando intento agregar una pagina web desde un formulario, pero al intentar subirlo me aparece

Error:

> INSERT INTO
>   latinsearch(pagina_nombre,pagina_link,pagina_keys,pagina_des,pagina_img,)
>   VALUES('Facebook','www.facebook.com','Facebook login, Facebook signup,
>   Facebook','Facebook es una red social creado por Mark Zuckerberg','')

Los datos no se suben a la base de datos, pero la imagen que viene incluida si se sube a la carpeta donde debe ir.

alguien me ayuda :(?

```
<?php

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "busqueda";
    $database = mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,$database);

    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $s_titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
        $s_link = $_POST["link"];
        $s_keywords = $_POST["keywords"];
        $s_descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
        $_simagen = $_FILES["imagen"] ["name"];

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"] ["tmp_name"], "img/". $_FILES["imagen"] ["name"]))
        {
            $sql="INSERT INTO latinsearch(pagina_nombre,pagina_link,pagina_keys,pagina_des,pagina_img,) VALUES('$s_titulo','$s_link','$s_keywords','$s_descripcion','$_imagen')";

            $aviso = mysqli_query($sql);

            if ($aviso)
            {
                echo "<script> alert('Correctamente')</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Y cual es el error que te sale?

Answer (score 2):

bueno tal vez suene un poco obvio, pero hay una coma demás en el último campo:

```
INSERT INTO latinsearch(pagina_nombre,pagina_link,pagina_keys,pagina_des,pagina_img,) 
                                                                                   ^
                                                                                   ^
                                                                                  ahi
```

Con respecto a la imagen, es normal que se suba sin ningun problema porque es independiente a la inserción de la base de datos.

Comment: Si esto es el error, entonces es un error tipografico y se cierra la pregunta por ese motivo

Comment: bueno quite el "," y aun me aparece eso, entonces que seria :(?